# What are the valid URL characters that can be used in a query variable?

Tags: url, character-encoding, guid

What are the valid characters that can be used in a URL query variable?

I'm asking because I would like to create GUIDs of minimal string length by using the largest character set so long as they can be passed as a URL query variable (www.StackOverflow.com?query=guiddaf09834fasnv)

### Edit

If you want to encode a UUID/GUID or any other information represented in a byte array into a url-friendly string, you can use this method in the [Apache Commons Code library](http://commons.apache.org/codec/):

```
Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(byte[])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When in doubt, just go to the **[RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt)**.

Note: A query variable is *not* dealt with any differently then the rest of the URL.

From the section **"2.2. URL Character Encoding Issues"**

> ... only alphanumerics, the special characters "$-_.+!*'(),", and reserved characters used for their reserved purposes may be used unencoded within a URL.